# Event Object Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to scripting and for a function(e) e is event object can anyone please update me for my few concerns

1. it will created when a event is triggered so when it will removed . so every event an object is created?
2. where these objects get stored?

Comment: Do you have any sample code to show us? It's kinda hard for us to answer a question about potential code problems without actual code.

Comment: @Chris i need just a theoretical update to brush up my mind that where the event objects get stored in browser memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just an event handler variable.

### Doesn't matter if its e or event

It really doesn't matter whether you use `e` or `event` or anyother word for this.

#### `function (e)`:

When you use this:

```
function (e) {
  // code..
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/kKb4H/1/ (fiddle for `function (e)`)

#### `function (event)`:

This is just a name you're giving to the current event, you can change that to

```
function (event) {
  // code..
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/kKb4H/2/ (fiddle for `function (event)`)

#### `function (something)`:

Or even to this:

```
function (something) {
  // code..
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/kKb4H/3/ (fiddle for `function (something)`)

### Their usage

You use these, to get the methods for the current object; such as event.keyCode, to get the keyCode which is used in a function where keyboard is used.

#### Where they are present

They are included in JavaScript and you don't need any more dependendies for it to work and you don't need any more coding work for it.

### What a function looks like

They aren't removed, once a function is executed, it has an event parameter or what you can call argument. as:

```
function (event) { // event is the argument
   if(event.keyCode == 13) { // using its method of keycode
      /* and comparing its value to 13
       * 13 is for enter
       * you get a bool value; either true of false and do the coding */
   }
}
```

### Simple answer

From the fiddles you will get to the result that `e` doesnot require to be `e` only. It can be anything that you want to be written in the code. Something is no method in JavaScript, but usage of it at the first argument made it an event handler, and it got the methods of `event`.

They are not stored in browser, they are a part of every browser! When you say a browser supports this feature it means it includes all the files that are required to run a code.